# Decrease AdSense visits/impressions after AMP implementation

Tags: wordpress, adsense, amp-html

I implemented AMP in several WordPress blogs, and after 2 weeks:

- Google Analytics Visits: OK
- AdSense reports that I have a decrease of visits, impressions, revenue

I implemented AdSense Ads in the AMP version, but it loads very slow.

I am thinking in disable AMP for this sites. What do you think?

In order to disable AMP in the sites, the procedure is just to disable the WP Plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is entirely what you're looking for but it seems the feature to disable the amp versions of some pages have been added in `version 0.7.7` of the [AMP Wordpress Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/accelerated-mobile-pages/). This has been confirmed in this [wordpress AMP forum](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/is-there-a-way-to-disable-amp-versions-of-some-pages/). You can also try disabling the plug-in as you've suggested.